# Hide "shot" after display:block

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

```
function increase() 
{ 
var counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML);
counter--; 
var add = counter -1;
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
```

// show an element
document.getElementById("shot").style.display = "block";

I press a button which displays "shot" but I want it to turn off again when I let go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the element, just use `display:none` :

```
// Hide your element
document.getElementById("shot").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work, I think the button is then calling both block and none at the same time maybe.

Comment: If that is the case, you could consider adding a delay that would hide it temporarily by using `setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("shot").style.display = "none"; }, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the element to hide when you let go you off the button you should use the onmouseup event like this:

**EDIT**: reordered input tag to be above so it doesn't move when text paragraph is hidden **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" onmousedown="show()" onmouseup="hide()" 
<p id="elem">Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.</p>
value="Toggle">
<script>
    function show() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
        elem.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hide() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks good I'll give it a try in a bit and let you know, thanks!